# Iterating a checkboxes using {{#each)) in blaze (Meteor)

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I have the following code`

```
{{# each item}}
    <p class="center">
     <input type="checkbox"  checked="checked" id="basiccbox" name={{id}} />
     <label for="basiccbox"> &nbsp;</label>
    </p>
{{/each}}
```

Multiple check boxes is now rendered. However, when i click any of the box, only the first check box toggles between the true or false states. This happens because of the

```
for="basiccbox"
```

and

```
id="basiccbox"
```

i.e all box that is rendered have the same Id. How do i generate unique ids or how does one deal with such a situation.

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

usually you should assign the **item._id** to **id** of checkbox tag. below is the code to solve your issue.

```
{{# each item}}
    <p class="center">
       <input type="checkbox"  checked="checked" id={{_id}} name={{id}} />
       <label for="basiccbox"> &nbsp;</label>
    </p>
{{/each}}
```

It is good to bind the document id somewhere for tag element, because you can use the same id to do DB operations as well.